# Why the response time of first call is longer than the following

Tags: java, web-services, apache-axis, httpresponse

I generated the stub by Axis2 Code Generator in eclipse.

And my client code is below:

```
ServerStub server = new ServerStub();

for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    java.sql.Timestamp requestTime = new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis());

    OperationResponse res = server.operation(new operation());

    System.out.println("Response Time: " + (System.currentTimeMillis() - requestTime.getTime()) + "ms");
}
```

Then I got the output:

```
Response Time: 371ms
Response Time: 13ms
Response Time: 16ms
Response Time: 14ms
Response Time: 11ms
```

Is there anyone can explain this? Thx.

P.S. the server and client are in the same network segment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference in time might be cause because of class loader. When you call first time the JVM need to prepare the code to be executable. That process take some time. To perform valid time test you should first "warm up" the JVM and load all required class.

Comment: Also it can be that it builds up the connection to the server and then reuses it later